# Converting a message in a channel into an embed

Tags: discord.js

I am currently trying to script that when a person sends a message to a specific channel, that message is then automatically converted to an embed. For me the conversion works the first time but not the second time. I'm always getting an error after the messages was converted.

My Script:

```js
const channel = "905504402276765766";
if(channel.includes(message.channel.id))

var test = message.content.slice(" ")
const tryembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

.setColor('DARK_RED')
.setTitle('Test')
.addFields(
    {name: "Person who wants to report a bug:", value: `<@!${message.author.id}>`},
    {name: "Bug that was reported:", value: test}
)

message.channel.send({embeds: [tryembed]})
message.delete()
```

My error Code:

```js
C:\Discord Bots\Bot v13\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Util.js:414
    if (!allowEmpty && data.length === 0) throw new error(errorMessage);
                                                ^

RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.
    at Function.verifyString (C:\Discord Bots\Bot v13\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Util.js:414:49)
    at Function.normalizeField (C:\Discord Bots\Bot v13\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:441:19)
    at C:\Discord Bots\Bot v13\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:462:14
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.normalizeFields (C:\Discord Bots\Bot v13\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:461:8)
    at MessageEmbed.addFields (C:\Discord Bots\Bot v13\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:283:42)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Discord Bots\Bot v13\index.js:44:2)
    at Client.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Discord Bots\Bot v13\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:23:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Discord Bots\Bot v13\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'EMBED_FIELD_VALUE'
}
```

Comment: What is the message content (`message.content`)?

Comment: The message that the person sends in the channel

Comment: What is the value of it? What do they send?

Comment: So for example you're trying to report a bug you found. So you're gonna send somenthing like: "I can't walk". So the value should exactly be that message

Comment: My question is *what do they send*?

Comment: A normal Discord Message

Comment: For example i write "This is a test". My script should convert that message in an embed: https://gyazo.com/fa883d4baa982fe53ca023bdbfe15148

Comment: Try putting braces (`{ }`) to enclose everything after the `if` statement

Comment: check type of test, should be string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `` value: `** ** ${test}` `` will solve your problem, so you need to change your `{name: "Bug that was reported:", value: test}` to:

```js
{name: "Bug that was reported:", value: `** ** ${test}`}
```